# How to retrieve arn of EFS filesystem accesspoints using aws-sdk-go?

Tags: go, amazon-efs, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to retrieve the arn of EFS filesystem using aws sdk go. But looks like the struct does not support retrieving details by Name. I dont know the filesystemid to fetch the arn. I only have Name. Is this still achievable?

```
svc := efs.New(session.New())
input := &efs.DescribeFileSystemsInput{
    
}

result, err := svc.DescribeFileSystems(input)
if err != nil {
    if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        switch aerr.Code() {
        case efs.ErrCodeBadRequest:
            fmt.Println(efs.ErrCodeBadRequest, aerr.Error())
        case efs.ErrCodeInternalServerError:
            fmt.Println(efs.ErrCodeInternalServerError, aerr.Error())
        case efs.ErrCodeFileSystemNotFound:
            fmt.Println(efs.ErrCodeFileSystemNotFound, aerr.Error())
        default:
            fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
        }
    } else {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    return
```

If I try to filter the below input by Name, struct is not supporting it.

```
input := &efs.DescribeFileSystemsInput{
        
    }
```

Even Name Tag key is not supported.

Is there any other method to fetch the arn for EFS? EFS has random numbers generated for arn. So I am unable to create arn. arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:xxxxx:access-point/fsap-xxxxxx

Comment: You may try to get all the file system using `DescribeFileSystems` and then filter out the output for given filesystem by name.

Comment: That is the solution I thought. But wanted to know if there is an option available out of box.